# FTP client code in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, ftp

I have been trying to download a file from an FTP server to the sdcard of the simulator through a FTP client. I have not been able to find a reference for how to code an FTP client. Can anyone please help or provide me a link where I can get a sample code of how to download a file using FTP? When I was working in an Android environment, I made use of an external jar file for FTP, but in Blackberry that same jar file is of no use.

Here is a sample code..

```
 public final class UploadScreen extends MainScreen
{
    File f;
public UploadScreen()
{        
    setTitle("File Upload");
    SimpleFTP ftp=new SimpleFTP();
    try {
        ftp.connect("14.97.146.41/xml/", 21);
        ftp.bin();
        f=new File("asd");

        boolean a=ftp.stor(f);

        if(a)
        {
            Dialog.alert("Done");
        }
        else
        {
            Dialog.alert("Fail");
        }
        ftp.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

Here simpleftp is a jar file that i have downloaded from "http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/"

Now here when i run this prog. it doesn't even run and crashes saying Module "SimpleFTP" not found.I have added external jar file to the project but still its not working. I read about preverfiying the jar files but when i try to do that from command prompt, it says

```
Error preverifying class org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

Please help this code is fro uploading but i have same problems for downloading

Comment: Waynn Lue- I have edited my question. Please have a look at it....

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry devices use Java-ME, and not Java-SE.   This is in contrast to Android devices, which are able to make use of unmodified Java-SE libraries.

At the language level, Java-ME requires Java 1.3 language compliance - this means no generics, no assert, no enums.   Most modern Java libraries use at least one of those features, but maybe you got lucky with SimpleFTP.

At the API level, Java-ME does not use the standard networking classes from Java-SE.  Instead you will have to use [Connector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html) and cast the result to a [StreamConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/javax/microedition/io/StreamConnection.html).  This is substantially different than what a Java-SE library will be doing.